# In C# Odata Server how do I add a filter without affecting the meta-url for the odata

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

In C# Odata Server how do I add a filter without affecting the meta-url for the odata service?

I currently add filters as this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)    
{
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended upp adding the the attribute "Authorize" to a base controller which all my other controllers inherit from. Now only the api requires authorization, not the meta-url.